# Complex conjugate of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and  $\alpha: V \rightarrow V$ 
a linear map. Is there a natural/consistent definition of the complex conjugate of $\alpha$?

I see that by choosing a basis for $V$ we could get one candidate for the complex conjugate but it seems to me that this "definition" is basis dependent (although the example I just tried suggested otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the complex conjugate map, defined by $$z \longmapsto \overline{z}?$$ This is a map $\overline{\alpha} : V \to \overline{V}$ into the complex conjugate vector space.